# TSQL - Remove Everything after the last period

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

I have a column string that may be one of the following.

```
10.0.2531.0
10.50.2500
10.0.2531.60
```

My requirement is, if there are 3 periods/decimal points, remove the last period/decimal and everything after that.

If I use the following, this will take care of the first row where there is only ".0", however, it does not work for the third row.

```
select 
case 
        when right(column_1,2) = '.0' then left(column_1,len(column_1)-2)
        else column_1 end,
FROM 
table_1
```

I also tried the following but that didn't work.

```
select 
case 
        when right(column_1,2) = '.' then left(column_1,len(column_1)-2)
        when right(column_1,3) = '.' then left(column_1,len(column_1)-3)
        else column_1 end,
FROM 
table_1
```

The number after the third period/decimal may be a 0 or another number.

Answer (score 3):

The following works, under the assumption that there are never five periods:

```
select (case when ip like '%.%.%.%'
             then left(ip, len(ip) - charindex('.', reverse(ip))
             else ip
        end) as firstThree
```

Comment: SQL Server has `LEN` function ;)

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Thanks.  I'm sitting here dealing with Oracle in another window.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `charindex` and `substring`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0afd/2)

```
select reverse(substring(reverse(column_1), charindex('.',reverse(column_1))+1, len(column_1))) 
from table_1
where len(column_1) - len(replace(column_1,'.','')) = 3
```